# Receive UDP datagram and parse source port

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to send commands using UDP. The receiver is supposed to receive the UDP datagram and reply. However, I would like the reply to always be sent to the sender's source port. I know how to parse the the port (struct header and move the pointer to the right position...), however, I'm looking for a function that returns the whole received frame including the headers and not only the datagram/data.

Comment: why do you want to use UDP for this?

Comment: I'm using UDP multicast. UDP seems more convenient when addressing a large number of receivers. Sure TCP works too. But the data aren't that critical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the `recvfrom()` function? It allows you to grab the data and it fills a `sockaddr` struct from which you can find the source port of the sender.

Comment: hmm didn't know recvfrom() would fill sockaddr. Thanks for the reply. I'm somewhat new to socket programming.